# how to popup window in windowDidBecomeKey

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(windowDidBecomeKey:) name:NSWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification object:nil];
```

I add observer for `name:NSWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification` and handle it

```
-(void)windowDidBecomeKey:(NSNotification*)notification
{
      NSWindowController *xxx;
      [xxx showWindow:self];
}
```

Then the windowDidBecomeKey will be called endless which cause to a infinite loop. So anybody know how to implement this function that show a popup when the window is activate?

Comment: You're observing all windows, including the new window. Specify the window you want to observe.

Comment: thanks, you are right.